# Is net force conservative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, work, conservative-field

From the work-energy theorem, $$\int_{C}^{}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}= \frac{1}{2}mv^2_f -\frac{1}{2}mv^2_i$$

Is velocity the gradient of position, and if so, does that make this force a conservative vector field?

Comment: Velocity is not the gradient of position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\vec F$ in your work energy equation is the *net* force acting on the object. The work energy theorem states that the *net* work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

A Force, or net force, is conservative if the work done by such a force between two points is independent of the path between the two points. That is not necessarily the if one of the forces comprising the net force acting on the object is not conservative. One such force is that of kinetic friction.  The work done by kinetic friction depends on the path.

For example, consider an object sliding down a frictionless incline plane of height $h$. The work done by gravity, a conservative force, on an object of mass $m$ will be $mgh$ regardless of angle of incline and thus the distance traveled $L$ down the incline, though the distance the object travels along the incline will vary with $\theta$. From the work energy theorem, assuming the object starts at rest and the final velocity at the bottom of the incline is $v_f$

$$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^2$$

or, equivalently,

$$mg\sin\theta L=\frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^2\tag{1}$$.

Where $mg\sin\theta$ is the component of the force of gravity acting down the incline and $L$ is the length of the incline equal to

$$L=\frac{h}{\sin\theta}\tag{2}$$

*Note that the work done by gravity, and thus the net work done, does not depend on $L$. It only depends on $h$*

Now let's consider the same scenario with kinetic friction between the object and the incline. A friction $f$ will act up the plane where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction.

$$f=\mu_{k}mg\cos\theta$$

Now the net force acting on the object down the incline will be

$$F_{net}=mg\sin\theta-\mu_{d}mg\cos\theta$$

applying the work energy theorem where the net force acts over the distance $L$

$$mg\sin\theta L-\mu_{d}mg\cos\theta L=\frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^2\tag{3}$$

Note that in equation (3), with friction, the work done on the object for a given height $h$ depends on the length $L$ of the incline, whereas the work done by gravity alone, equation (1), does not depend on $L$ due to the relationship in equation (2).

***Bottom line: The net force (and thus net work) is not conservative if one of the forces (e.g., friction) is non conservative.***

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it does not have to be conservative. Newton's second law is
$$
m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}=\mathbf{F}(t)
$$
Myltiplying this by $\mathbf{v}$ we have
$$
m\mathbf{v}\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}= \frac{d}{dt}\frac{m\mathbf{v}^2}{2}=\mathbf{F}(t)\cdot\mathbf{v}(t)=\mathbf{F}(t)\cdot\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}
$$
Integrating from $t_i$ to $t_f$:
$$
\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{m\mathbf{v}^2}{2}dt=
\frac{m\mathbf{v}^2_f}{2}-\frac{m\mathbf{v}^2_i}{2}=
\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathbf{F}(t)\cdot\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}dt=
\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\mathbf{F}(t)\cdot d\mathbf{r}(t)
$$
If the Force does not contain explicit time dependence (but only dependent on $\mathbf{r}$), then the last integral is equal to
$$
\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_f}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot d\mathbf{r},
$$
where the integration is along the motion path. One does not use the conservative nature of the force anywhere in this derivation. However, if the force *is* conservative, then this integral will be path-independent, i.e., it will be simply the difference of potential energies:
$$
\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_f}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot d\mathbf{r} =U(\mathbf{r}_f)-U(\mathbf{r}_i).
$$